# Can we use socket.io two times?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I have such a question, can I use socket.io two times in react js? I mean when I have this code:

```
    const socket = useRef();
    socket.current = io("ws://localhost:5000");
```

can I use such code in another component? I mean copy-paste, if not then How can I use socket.io as a global variable in reactjs

Comment: Create a context

Comment: I did it but I want to know if I have another way to make it

Comment: Why do you want to use a different way instead of using the good way?

Comment: why not send the socket over props to the childrens/compo?

Comment: @konrad because I have many contexts and I don't want to make context for small things

Comment: This is the correct way - to make context for small things

Comment: @StefanBD not working, I don't know why

Comment: @Konrad okay thank's for the answer

Comment: can u supply more code?

Comment: import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
import Child from "child.js"

export default function ClientComponent() {

const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
  const socket = socketIOClient("http://127.0.0.1:4001");
  setSocket(socket)
}, []);


return (
  <p>
   <Child socket={socket}/>
  </p>
);

}

And in child u can acces it with props.axios, this is how its works on my side